# pgadmin error while connecting to docker postgres instance: "The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request."

Tags: postgresql, powershell, docker, pgadmin

I'm running a postgres image from a docker container. While trying to access it from the pgadmin 4 GUI client, I'm getting the error: "The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

After connecting to the docker instance, the pgadmin GUI displays the default `postgres` database, but there is a cross on the other databases which I had created from within the container.

After refreshing connection multiple times I get a message along the lines of connection made to database, but it doesn't actually load in the GUI.

How do I connect to those databases?

(I'm running docker in Windows 10 powershell with admin privileges)

Comment: could you post your configuration please?

Answer (score 0):

Made changes as per the suggestion [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAKKotZTN56RaPuNunDck5C9%2BLKGFzoQ5DtpGxt7zhxiu%2BNRHow%40mail.gmail.com).

Restarted pdadmin, and started container in non-admin mode.

Able to retrieve and commit data.